# Junit test can't pass all test case once

Tags: java, junit

I have a very strange problem, when i try to run a JUnit test with multiple test case, it will only pass the first test case and shown `IndexOut of Bound` error

```
public class ABCTest {
    @Test
    public void basicTest1(){...}
    @Test
    public void basicTest2(){...}
    ...
```

but if i commend the rest test case, test them one by one, it will pass all of them.

```
public class ABCTest {    
    @Test
    public void basicTest1(){...}
    //@Test
    //public void basicTest2(){...}
    //...
```

Comment: You likely need to do some setup and teardown for each test.

Comment: Are they using the same data or something that is removed by one of those tests?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza the test case all unique one

Comment: you should paste the stack-trace .. is it originating in your own code, your test-code, or the junit framework itself?

Comment: @Cruncher i'm wondering how to do it? so if it can pass all the test individually, means is my junit test problem, won't be my code issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you do not provide the complete testcase and implementation class, I have to make some assumptions.

Most likely you are mutating the state of the tested object by the testcase.

Usually you try to get a clean test fixture for each unit test. This works by having a method with the @Before annotation which creates a new instance of the class under test. (This was called 'setUp()' in older versions of junit.)

This ensures that the order of test method execution as well as the number of executions does not matter and each method is working isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are doing inside of the test case and see if you are changing data that may be used by the other test cases and not restoring it to the original state. For example you have a text file that you read and write to in basicTest1 that you then read again in basicTest2 but assume the file is the same as it was before you ran basicTest1.

This is just one possible problem. would need to see the code for more insight